# $x^TAx$ and the eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, regression

Let A denote a symmetric matrix in $\mathbb R^{N\times N}$, and let $f$ denote the function defined for all $x\in \mathbb R^{N}$\{0} by

$$f(x) = \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$$

Let $\lambda_1,....,\lambda_N$ denote the eigenvalues of A. Prove that

$$\min_x f(x) = \min_i \lambda_i$$
and
$$\max_x f(x) = \max_i \lambda_i$$

------My Solution (Incomplete)------

I have computed the gradient of $f$, which is $\frac{2[Ax(x^Tx)-x(x^TAx)]}{(x^Tx)^2}$. Therefore when the gradient is 0, from $2[Ax(x^Tx)-x(x^TAx)]$,  I get $Ax = \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}x$.

This seems to correspond to the eigenvalue formula $Ax = \lambda x$. But from here I am stuck and nowhere to find the solution. Woule anybody please help me?

Comment: can you do this for the case when $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: Since nobody corrected you yet: $\mathbf x^\top\mathbf A\mathbf x$ is a *scalar* and not a matrix. What you intended to say in the title (which I have now fixed) is that you are interested in the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$.

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is symmetric therefore diagonalisable in an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Let $(e_i)$ be that basis and write

$$x=\sum_ix_ie_i,A e_i=\lambda_ie_i$$

One then has

$$f(x)={\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2\over \sum_ix_i^2}$$

Let’s give the details of the computation

$$\begin{align}x^TAx&=x^TA\sum_ix_ie_i\\
&=x^T\sum_ix_i\lambda_ie_i\text{    By linearity and definition of eigenvector}\\
&=\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2\text{     Because the basis is orthonormal}\end{align}$$

Now denote $\max\lambda_i=\lambda_M$ and $\min\lambda_i=\lambda_m$
One has $\lambda_m\leq\lambda_i\leq\lambda_M$ and therefore

$$\lambda_m\leq f(x)\leq\lambda_M$$

Besides $f(e_m)=\lambda_m$ and $f(e_M)=\lambda_M$ and we’re done because we’ve proven that $f$ is bounded by $\min\lambda_i$ and $\max\lambda_i$ and reaches those bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment. However I don't understand why $x=\sum_ix_ie_i$, and why you can replace $\mathbf x^\top\mathbf A\mathbf x$ with $\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2$. Would you please explain step by step?

Comment: I just edited for more details